# reverse video rotating sometimes IOS

Tags: ios, swift, video

I'm using this library  Reverse-AVAsset-Efficient (https://github.com/whydna/Reverse-AVAsset-Efficient) to rotate videos.

It works perfectly. But If the video is recorded in phone and if I try to reverse it, I am getting the video in landscape [Orientation --> Left].

I want all videos in portrait (Same orientation as source file).

I am trying to explain is I am getting video rotated that I don't want. Please provide me solution.

Still you are not understanding try to reverse recorded video with this library. I've also attached images

Comment: Then what is your question? 
read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: I dont want that rotated video I want that video as it was in portrait.

Comment: Jack, sorry but its very difficult to understand your question. Try have some English speaker help you translate your thoughts.

Comment: Ok.. I am trying again..